# Title for netbeans project window

Tags: java, netbeans, titlebar

I need to give a title for  netbeans project window for showing the purpose of the window

JFrame myFrame=new JFrame(" Title "); ?

Any one to help?

Comment: Don't forget to mark a question as answered if your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That can work too,  generally the best recommended way is to use the function *setTitle*.

> `JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();`
>   `myFrame.setTitle("title here");`

Answer (score 0):

There is an overloaded constructor for [JFrame(String title)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame(java.lang.String)) or you can use [setTitle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) method.

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("your frame title");
```

or

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
myFrame.setTitle("your frame title");
```